# strange class of output in R

Tags: r, eval

There are some trouble when I try to using *eval()* and then *knn()*:

```
library(ISLR)
library(stringr)
train <- Weekly[Weekly$Year>=1990&Weekly$Year<=2008,]
test <- Weekly[!(Weekly$Year>=1990&Weekly$Year<=2008),]
coefAll <- combn(c("Lag1","Lag2","Lag3","Lag4","Lag5","Volume"),2, simplify = F)
coef <- coefAll[[1]]
modeltrain <- str_c("train.X <- matrix(train[,","c(\"",str_c(coef, collapse = '\",\"'),"\")])")
modeltest <- str_c("test.X <- matrix(test[,","c(\"",str_c(coef, collapse = '\",\"'),"\")])")
eval(parse(text = modeltrain))
eval(parse(text = modeltest))
Direction <- train[,"Direction"] 
knn.pred <- knn (train.X,test.X,Direction ,k=3)
```

The error is reported as follows:

```
Error in knn(train.X, test.X, Direction, k = k) : 
  'train' and 'class' have different lengths
```

Then I Looking at the structure of train.X:

```
     [,1]        
[1,] Numeric,985
[2,] Numeric,985
```

I have never seen this strange structure before, and I don't know which step is wrong(maybe the *eval()*?).
Thank you~

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? Why not directly `train.X <- matrix(train.....` ?

Comment: Because this code is just a sample of the original. I tried to use all combinations of variables and see which is the best, and the combinations were made character, which may need eval To run.